# In an agile board, how can I order the subtasks inside the parent task card

Tags: youtrack

I have a parent task and I added subtasks. On my agile board I can see that parent task and having chosen to view "with description" I also can see the subtasks inside the parent tasks card in a nice ordered list format. I can even click on any of them and open it directly.

What I can't find is how to order this list which always seems to be ordered by creation time of subtasks. If I can't order this list my self, I need to be going back to Tree-view every time to figure out in what order the subtasks should be performed.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's impossible. Subtasks of the issue on a card are just taken from the database in the order of creation and displayed in this very order, without an opportunity to set custom order for them.

Probably the best workaround for you now is to make each issue with many subtasks a separate swimlane and then organize the order of subtasks by moving cards.